# How to run async methods in langchain?

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I have a basic chain that classifies some text based on the Common European Framework of Reference for Languages. I'm timing the difference between normal `chain.apply` and `chain.aapply` but can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```py
import os
from time import time

import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0)

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
    'Classify the text based on the Common European Framework of Reference '
    'for Languages (CEFR). Give a single value: {text}',
)
chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)

texts = [
    {'text': 'Hallo, ich bin 25 Jahre alt.'},
    {'text': 'Wie geht es dir?'},
    {'text': 'In meiner Freizeit, spiele ich gerne Fussball.'}
]

start = time()
res_a = chain.apply(texts)
print(res_a)
print(f"apply time taken: {time() - start:.2f} seconds")
print()

start = time()
res_aa = chain.aapply(texts)
print(res_aa)
print(f"aapply time taken: {time() - start:.2f} seconds")
```

Output

```
[{'text': 'Based on the given text "Hallo, ich bin 25 Jahre alt," it can be classified as CEFR level A1.'}, {'text': 'A2'}, {'text': 'A2'}]
apply time taken: 2.24 seconds

<coroutine object LLMChain.aapply at 0x0000025EA95BE3B0>
aapply time taken: 0.00 seconds

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13620\1566967258.py:34: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'LLMChain.aapply' was never awaited
  res_aa = chain.aapply(texts)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```py
res_aa = chain.aapply(texts)
```

to

```py
res_aa = await chain.aapply(texts)
```

did the job!

Now it works (damn these methods are much faster than doing it sequentially)

```
[{'text': 'Based on the given text "Hallo, ich bin 25 Jahre alt," it can be classified as CEFR level A1.'}, {'text': 'A2'}, {'text': 'A2'}]
apply time taken: 2.87 seconds

[{'text': 'Based on the given text "Hallo, ich bin 25 Jahre alt," it can be classified as CEFR level A1.'}, {'text': 'A2'}, {'text': 'A2'}]
aapply time taken: 1.34 seconds
```

Comment: Does it not give you an error '"await" allowed only within async function'? I get that error when I try to use agent_excecutor.arun(query)

Comment: Yes it does if you are running it in a python script. I was using it in a notebook. You need to wrap it in a function `asycn def f(x):` and then `await f(x)`, potentially with `asyncio.run(f(x))`

Comment: I could not get it to work when I wrapped it in a function; langchain kept throwing errors about missing inputs and keys...

Comment: Were you creating it the way I did? Or with the LCEL syntax? Feel free to paste your error here and I can help you out